NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRoute
enter image description here
Ich bekomme den Fehler NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRoute! in meiner Angular-Anwendung. Dieser Fehler tritt auf, wenn ich versuche, den ActivatedRoute-Dienst in meiner ModuleDetailComponent-Komponente zu verwenden. Das bedeutet, dass Angular keinen Anbieter für ActivatedRoute finden kann.
Ich habe erwartet, dass ActivatedRoute korrekt injiziert wird, damit ich auf die Routenparameter zugreifen kann. Ich habe überprüft, ob ActivatedRoute in meiner Komponente korrekt importiert ist, aber der Fehler bleibt bestehen.

Hi Coletto, It would be better to provide more details about your code.

Bitte auf Englisch schreiben. Keine Screenshots von Code, Fehlern, Logs und ähnlichem posten, alles als formatierter Text in einem [code block]. Und immer ein [mcve] posten. Siehe [ask].

If you're using standaloneComponent see taht if you're using routerLink or RouterLinkActive or RouterOutlet you need to add them RouterLinkActive, and RouterOutlet to the imports array (the ActivatedRouter not should be in the imports
Remember also that, when use routes in standalone component you need add providers: [provideRouter(routes)]
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(APP_ROUTES),
    ...
  ]
}

And import the RouterModule in your appComponent
